# Custom Action Step (mobile) in Testim - Appium server does not support executeDriverScript method

Tags: appium-android, testim.io

I am new to testim and I am  trying to understand how to use the step custom action, to test some functionalities in my mobile App.
I tried the example from documentation (https://help.testim.io/docs/execute-driver-script-step) but I keep getting the error:

**STEP FAILED: Appium server does not support executeDriverScript method.**

I tried to keep the step empty with no code, but I still I get the same error.

Any hints?
Thanks